# Force child to inherit parent color on hover

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a table where in each column they have a different color for the text part.

What I like to do on a row hovering is to highlight with the background and have all the text shift to one color instead of their individual colors on normal showing.

Below is my code. You will see purple, great, black text. Then when it hovers, only the black text shifts to red.

Now I have tried putting a hover for each individual `<td>` column but that did not work. The hover color would only change text color when the mouse was specifically over the TD cell not when any of the cells where being hovered over for that particular row.

```css
.musicListTracks h5 {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.musicListTracks tr:hover {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: red !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.musicListTracks tr td:nth-child(1) span {
  color: #8470FF;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.musicListTracks tr td:nth-child(2) h5 {
  color: darkgrey;
}
```

```html
<table class="musicListTracks" cellpadding=5 cellspacing=0>
  <tr>
    <td><span>cell 1</span></td>
    <td>
      <h5>cell 2</h5>
    </td>
    <td>
      <h5>cell 3</h5>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span>cell 1b</span></td>
    <td>
      <h5>cell 2b</h5>
    </td>
    <td>
      <h5>cell 3b</h5>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span>cell 1c</span></td>
    <td>
      <h5>cell 2c</h5>
    </td>
    <td>
      <h5>cell 3c</h5>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have colors defined for the first two cells, but not the third. That's why only the third cell takes the red color on hover.

Instead of this:

```
.musicListTracks tr:hover {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: red !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Try this:

```
.musicListTracks tr:hover {
  background-color: #000000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.musicListTracks tr:hover * {
  color: red !important;
}
```

```css
.musicListTracks h5 {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.musicListTracks tr:hover {
  background-color: #000000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.musicListTracks tr:hover * {
  color: red !important;
}

.musicListTracks tr td:nth-child(1) span {
  color: #8470FF;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.musicListTracks tr td:nth-child(2) h5 {
  color: darkgrey;
}
```

```html
<table class="musicListTracks" cellpadding=5 cellspacing=0>
  <tr>
    <td><span>cell 1</span></td>
    <td>
      <h5>cell 2</h5>
    </td>
    <td>
      <h5>cell 3</h5>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span>cell 1b</span></td>
    <td>
      <h5>cell 2b</h5>
    </td>
    <td>
      <h5>cell 3b</h5>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span>cell 1c</span></td>
    <td>
      <h5>cell 2c</h5>
    </td>
    <td>
      <h5>cell 3c</h5>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Oh Man Michael_B thanks so much.  I spent a couple of hours last night and a couple of hours today trying to find the answer... I so greatly appreciate your time and your answer.  It worked like a champ!

Answer (score 1):

Michael is correct in his answer in that you aren't targeting all the elements inside the tds.  His answer uses the wildcard to target any element inside your td.  If that is what you want, his answer would be best.  If you want to target only the span and h5, you can use the following:

```
.musicListTracks tr:hover {
    background-color: #000000;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.musicListTracks tr:hover td {
    color: red !important;
}

.musicListTracks tr:hover h5 {
    color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: thanks so much for taking the time and for your answer.  I did want to target all the cells... And your solution I found works as well if you wanted to target individual cells separately.